# Getting power state of a Azure VM using Java SDK is very slow

Tags: azure, azure-java-sdk

I am using version 1.1.2 of the Azure JAVA SDK.

The API call for getting the powerstate of a VM is taking too long to respond.On an average it takes around ~8 seconds to get the power state of a single VM.

Our subscription of around 30 VMs takes 260 seconds just to get the powerstate of all VM's.

Is there a workaround here ?

Comment: have you looked at the ARM API? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/get

Comment: Yes this returns the 'provisioningState' but not the 'powerState'